# Sufficient Conditions for Differentiability--Partial Derivatives for $f(x,y) = \frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

There are no examples in the text to go by, so I am not sure which direction to go with this one:

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2 + y^2}$ if $x^2 + y^2 \neq 0$, and define $f(0,0)=0$. Show that $f$ has first partial derivatives at all points, satisfying the inequalities $|f_1(x,y)|\leq 6|x|$, $|f_2(x,y)| \leq 6|y|$. Is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

**Note, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the partials with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively. 
$$f_1 = \frac{4x^3(x^2 + y^2) - 2x(x^4 + y^4)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$
$$f_2 = \frac{4y^3(x^2 + y^2) - 2y(x^4 + y^4)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$$

Except, when $f(0,0) = 0$, then 
$$f_1 = 0$$
$$f_2 = 0$$

I do not understand how to make the connection with each of these being less than or equal to $6|x|$ and $6|y|$ respectively.

Comment: How are $f_{j}(x,y)$ defined in relation to $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Do you mean what are the partial derivatives? The partial derivatives for $x$ and $y$ are $\frac{4x^3(x^2 + y^2) - 2x(x^4 + y^4)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$ and $\frac{4y^3(x^2 + y^2) - 2y(x^4 + y^4)}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$, respectively.

Comment: No, I assume that you mean $f_{1}(x,y)=f_{x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$ but wasn't certain so I thought that I would ask.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. That is the notation that my textbook uses.

Comment: there is a result that if the partial derivatives are continuous at say $z=(x,y)$, then the function is differentiable at $z$.

Comment: Theorem II in my text says that "A function of several variables is differentiable at a point if the function and all its first partial derivatives are defined in some neighborhood of the point and if these derivatives are continuous at the point." I think I showed in my edit that the partials are defined in some neighborhood of the point. However, how do I show that they are continuous and show the relationship $f_x \leq 6|x|$?

Comment: $f_1(0) = 0$. Now, what is the limit of $f_1(x,y)$ for $(x,y)\to 0$?

Comment: Use the limit definition for partial derivatives,

Comment: Use the limit definition for partial derivatives, $f(h,0) = h^2$. Thus, $f_1(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = \frac{h^2}{h} = h = 0$ because we are limiting h to 0. That again establishes that $f_1(0)=0$, but I do not know how to find the limit of $f_1$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow 0$$. I guess I am still lost!

Comment: @user251257 After doing some work, I believe the limit of $f_1(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \rightarrow 0$ is $0$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Josh okay. for $f_2$ it is analogous. now, you can apply the theorem found in your book

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to see if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$: We know $f_1(0,0) = 0,f_2(0,0)=0.$ That tells you $Df(0,0),$ if it exists, is just the $0$ transformation. So hint: Is it true that

$$f(x,y) - f(0,0) = 0 + o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$$

as $(x,y) \to (0,0)?$

Comment: Is that supposed to be a zero (0) in front of the second part of the equation? Using the multi-variable limit definition, $\sqrt{(x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2}$ produces $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. Where are you getting the zero or "o" or whatever that is front of that part of the equation?

Comment: Yes, that's a $0.$ That's because the only candidate for $Df(0,0)$ is the $0$ linear map. $o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$ is standard notation for a function $g$ such that $g(x,y)/\sqrt {x^2+y^2} \to 0.$